# React setState not working after deleting data from state copy

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React web app, one of my component has the so-structured state :

```
state = {
    clientList : {
        client1 : { // some data },
        client2: { //some data },
        client3: { //some data }
    }
}
```

By clicking a button, client-2 should be deleted from state.
Here is the function to do so :

```
let clientList = {...this.state.clientList} 
// console.log(clientList) returns the whole state, as expected

delete clientList.client2  
// console.log(clientList) returns the updated state, client2 has been deleted, as expected

this.setState({ clientList })
```

But the component's state is not updated.
Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, I often do state updates like this, but it's the first time I use `delete` method.

One last thing : the data are given by Firebase, I cannot change de json structured data.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't this `this.setState({ clientList })` be `this.setState({ clientList : clientList  })`

Comment: @kiranvj this is valid since `es2015` see [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating the state object, which is a [big no-no in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data).

What you can do is [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the object out of the state (while creating a new object with no mutations).

and set the state with the rest of the objects:

```
const { client2, ...restOfClients } = clientList;
this.setState({ clientList: restOfClients });
```

Of course you will need to do it dynamically instead of hard-coding the `client2` key.

Here is a running example, note the commented lines on how to do it dynamically.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    clientList: {
      client1: { id: "client1" },
      client2: { id: "client2" },
      client3: { id: "client3" }
    }
  };

  deleteClient = () => {
    const { clientList } = this.state;
    //if you get the key you want to remove as a parameter:
    //const clientToRemove = "client2";
    //you can desstructure it out, example:
    //const { [clientToRemove]: removeMe, ...restOfClients} = clientList;

    // hardcoded client2 removal
    const { client2, ...restOfClients } = clientList;
    this.setState({ clientList: restOfClients });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.deleteClient}>Delete</button>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state.clientList)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: is there a reason you re-opened the question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and for pointing my bad pratices.

I tried the hardcoded solution, `console.log(restOfClients)` returns expected data, but setState still not working.

I also tried with a dynamic parameter, `console.log(restOfClients)` returns the initial state, no modifications.

I'm still confused...

Comment: when you say _"but setState still not working"_, do you get an error? how do you know its not working?

Comment: Again, how do you know it remains the same?

Comment: There is no change on the UI that display clients data, react devtools dont change, and so firebase data.
I dont expect changes in the dynamic case, because `console.log(restOfClients)` doesn't return the expected data.

I'm confused with that no changing state in the hardcoded case

Comment: where is your `console.log(restOfClients)` located? in the `setState` callback or outside of it? remember, `setState` is asynchronous.

Comment: OK, I tried my local code in a stack overflow code snippet and it works well. I will close this question and mark it as resolved : your answer work outside of my app.
Thank you again.

Comment: Great, if you have other problems with your code feel free to post a new question

Answer (score 0):

I have two alternatives here:

1.

```
this.setState({
     ...this.state,
     clientList: {
          ...this.state.clientList,
          client2: undefined     // <~~ I made it undefined
     }
})
```

2.

```
let clientList = {
    client1: this.state.client1,
    client3: this.state.client3       
}

this.setState({clientList})
```

Try those then picking one solution that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting data, We get to update the state. That is as follow,

```
this.setState({
  clientList : clientList 
});
```

This is the way how we update the state. Try this, hope, it works for you. :)

Comment: That's not true, there's no difference. it's only syntactic sugar. this is valid since `es2015` see [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)